# Normals and vertex normals are correct, but faces are showing black in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, normals

I imported this FBX and some faces on the model are looking weird.

The normals and vertex normals are correct... I already cleaned "custom split normals data" but the problem still exists... What could be wrong with the model?

Thanks!

[image: vertex normals / face normals / cycles render preview]

Comment: The material could be wrong.

Comment: The material is the same in all the faces. I was able to "solve" the problem by separate the wrong faces (each wrong face is now an object). It looks good on render now but it's still a little weird...